# CSS selector error in label

Tags: css, groovy

I am trying to assert following via CSS selector

```
<label class="Label TextStyle08 sg_selected" for="username">Username</label>
```

Code:

```
assert $("#loginForm :nth-child(1)").text() == "Username"
```

Failling woth below error though

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: Assertion failed:

```
assert $("#loginForm :nth-child(1)").text() == "Username"
       |                             |      |
       []                            null   false

    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
```

[image]

What could be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You shouldn't use space in between selectors unless necessary, and nth-child() affects the  hierarchy level rather than siblings of the same type and level**

---

This would be an explanation for your problem:

`#loginform :nth-child(1)` - The space between the two parts would mean that **any element inside #loginform could be selected.**

`:nth-child(1)` - is not called on any element *(like `p:nth-child(1)`)*, so it would mean **any element** (which would have been 'any p element', if the other case was considered) **which is a first child of any element.**

`$("#loginForm :nth-child(1)")`, would select **any first child, inside any element, within `#loginform`**...

---

So, considering all the elements within `#loginform`, these are selected:

- The first is `.FormLine`, which has a `:nth-child(1)` a `label` . So text : **'Username'**
- The next is `label', which has no`:nth-child(1). So text : **' '**
- The next is `.InpuWrap`, which has a `:nth-child(1)` a `p` . So text : **' '**
- The next is `.InpuBound`, which has a `:nth-child(1)` an `input` . So text : **' '**
- The next is `.ClearItem`, which has no `:nth-child(1)`. So text : **' '**
- The next is the second `.FormLine`, which has a `:nth-child(1)` a `label` . So text : **'Password'**
- Then the `span`, the `div` after that.... and so on... until each and every element inside `#loginform` is scanned for a `:nth-child(1)` and its `text()` output...

---

Here try this:

`assert $("#loginForm>.FormLine:nth-of-type(1) label").text() == "Username";`

OR

`assert $("#loginForm>:nth-child(1)>label").text() == "Username";`

All good?

Comment: I tried what you suggested. It's interesting bcuz, it produce another error which is closer to the solution `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: Assertion failed: 

assert $("#loginForm:nth-child(1)").text() == "Username"
       |                            |      |
       |                            |      false
       |                            Username
       |                            Password 
       [[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (b73111dd89cc00752c01344ee454cc07)] -> tag name: html]] -> css selector: #loginForm:nth-child(1)]] ` Getting two values

Comment: or maybe, you could use this. Try this and let me know... $("#loginForm>label:nth-of-type(1)").text() == "Username"

Comment: The second change gave me the initial error. I have attached `html ` part to the question anyway.

Comment: sorry i did'nt have the html... this is what you need $("#loginForm label:nth-of-type(1)").text() == "Username"

Comment: No problem at all. Still no luck though.

Comment: OK. then there is only one more way, I can suggest, given that there should be only one label within a '.FormLine': $("#loginForm>.FormLine:nth-of-type(1) label").text() == "Username"

Comment: this should select the label inside the first FormLine within loginForm.

Comment: Excellent. that resolved the issue. I am using `http://selectorgadget.com/ ` to find the `CSS selector ` which gives the  output as the one I specified in the question. Is there a any other tool which you can recommand?

Comment: I found even this works `$("#loginForm>:nth-child(1) label").text() == "Username" ` . Thanks to BlackPanther. I am still curious on my previous comments though.

Comment: @MPH : `$("#loginForm>:nth-child(1) label").text() == "Username"` is also good, that lies closer to the way you used in the question. I just got messed up with `:nth-child()`, so thought `:nth-of-type()` would be good. Either way, it is the same thing. In the first case, you select the the 'first immediate child', which is the first `.FormLine` and the label inside it. In my method, you select the first `.FormLine` directly and the label inside it.

Comment: I included your suggestion too into the answer, cuz you know, people don't often look into comments, once they get an answer upfront. @MPH